# Check for .net framework version installed

Tags: c#

Is there a reliable way to check for the latest .NET Framework version installed ? Most of the previous questions on this site are really old so I'm asking to see if there is a more updated method.

Comment: You can check in the registry, or, if you have visual studio installed, go to `Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio`, there you should see your current version.

Comment: Do You wanna check for the latest or an specific version?

Comment: @Milan I'm trying to find this out programmatically via C#.

Comment: @Virgil Just the latest version installed on the clients computer.

Comment: check the link above, i believe  you will find your answer there.

Comment: Problem is. That question is 7 years old. Isn't there a better way of doing this now ?

Comment: That's not a problem. The accepted answer has been updated many times since then, including information for v4.5+.

Comment: Learn about the site. It was revised [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/951915/revisions)